# Arm may not be usable for TBB windows users. What are the alternatives?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, nyx

The [anonymizing relay monitor (arm)](https://www.atagar.com/arm/) may not be usable for TBB windows users (or is it?). What alternatives exist for TBB window users?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean by ARM? The CPU architecture? How is it connected to TBB on Windows?

Comment: Dear Pabouk, ARM as Terminal (command line) application for monitoring and configuring Tor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is [Vidalia](https://www.torproject.org/projects/vidalia.html.en). This must be installed manually. However one of the Tor developers has some [pre-built binaries](https://people.torproject.org/~erinn/vidalia-standalone-bundles/). Select the one which fits you best and download it. You can extract (or execute in Windows) the package to any directory. Within the extracted files is a script called `start-vidalia`. When you execute it Vidalia comes up.

When Vidalia doesn't connect automatically to a running Tor instance, you'll have to configure it. Click on *Settings* and find a line with the word *tor*. On the right side is a button *Browse*. Click on it and enter the correct path to your Tor executable. This is usually the subdirectory `Tor` of your TBB installation. Now save your settings.

Try to play around or use Vidalia as you're used to.

You might also want to have a look a trac entry [#8641](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8641). The transition from Vidalia to another solution is discussed there. Probably other solutions can be found in the future there.